# When will ScriptSharp 0.8 be the official build?

Tags: script#

We are looking at adopting ScriptSharp into our project.  We don't want to take on 0.7.5 though if 0.8 is about to become the official version.

Can you give some indication on the likely timeline, i.e. weeks, months or years?

Also, if we adopt 0.7.5 will there be a mass of pain moving to 0.8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's around the corner barring some last minute things like documentation. We are already using it in production for two projects since November and its been working great so far!

I would recommend getting the latest cc branch and working with it which is 0.8. Moving from 7 to 8 won't be painful but can be slightly involved depending on the feature you use. Most of all there are a ton of new features in .8 such as html5 and nodejs, etc. I've used most of the features that .8 has to offer and they're very stable. Generally you won't run into any issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are stuck with VS2010 here as our parent company cannot get its act together, and so we cannot build the 0.8 code ourselves.

Comment: You can download the zip @ https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/archive/cc.zip. I'm not sure if 2012 is a requirement for it though.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I think that's still just the source. You could try building on express if you just need the binaries?

Comment: I think you might need VS2012 for things like the project templates. At the very least you'll certainly need .NET 4  to be able to runt the compiler etc. Is VS2012 Web Express an option?

I will look into sharing a set of pre-built binaries. Used to do that when github had a downloads section in each repository...

Comment: Location for latest pre-built binaries: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26621494/Releases/ScriptSharp.0.8.zip